# Getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function site_url()" after redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, url, redirect

I am creating a WordPress Plugin and I am using a wp_redirect() on one page to go to another.

On the first file, I use wp_redirect(), which takes a URL as an argument, built using site_url().

After the redirect, on the second file, if i try to call site_url(), or wp_redirect(), or home_url(), I get messages like this: "***Fatal error: Call to undefined function site_url()...***", the same for wp_redirect() and home_url().

It seems that these functions are not recognized.

I mention that these 2 files are in the same directory.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `wp_redirect` is intended to redirect to a page that is not on your WP site. Is that what you are intending? Otherwise if you want to redirect to another page that is in your WP install why not just use a link? Maybe share your code so we can see exactly what you are trying to do. Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: By URL i meant the link to the second file, which is in the same folder as the first one, in which i create the redirect. I managed to make it work by including "wp-load.php" in the second file.

Comment: `wp-load` is to literally load up WordPress at the beginning of loading your site. Seems like an anti-pattern to be navigating this way. The more common way to navigate is using page/post URL's that correspond to your PHP files by the template hierarchy logic. Unless there is some very specific reason you need to exit WP altogether and then restart it again on the next view, this feels like the wrong way to go. Another important resource: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will read the resources you provided. I am new to WordPress and this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, i managed to make it work.

I included "**wp-load.php**" in the second file, and now it works fine.